# CMake - Variable obtained through `get_target_property` set to <variable>-NOTFOUND

Tags: cmake

I've been trying to figure this out for all of yesterday and up to now today, I'm trying to configure a manifest file with the file name of the plugin

Currently I've got:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

function(printv)
        foreach(var ${ARGN})
                message("${var} = ${${var}}")
        endforeach()
endfunction()

function(printenv)
        foreach(var ${ARGN})
                message("${var} = $ENV{${var}}")
        endforeach()
endfunction()

project(SimpleAmp VERSION 1.0 HOMEPAGE_URL https://jghfunrun.github.io/plugins/simple-amp)
set(PROJECT_URI ${PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL})

add_library(amp MODULE amp.c)

get_target_property(PLUGIN_FILE amp LIBRARY_OUTPUT_NAME)

printv(PLUGIN_FILE PROJECT_URI)

configure_file(manifest.ttl.in manifest.ttl)
configure_file(amp.ttl.in amp.ttl)
```

Manifest.ttl.in

```
@prefix lv2:  <http://lv2plug.in/ns/lv2core#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<${PROJECT_URI}>
        a lv2:Plugin ;
        lv2:binary <${PLUGIN_FILE}> ;
        rdfs:seeAlso <amp.ttl> .
```

However the `lv2:binary` line becomes

```
lv2:binary <PLUGIN_FILE-NOTFOUND> ;
```

I also tried using the line `set(PLUGIN_FILE $<TARGET_FILE_NAME:amp>)` but that had no chance of working because `set` is evaluated during configuration and generator expressions are evaluated during generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by returning to the set method and adding

```
file(GENERATE
     OUTPUT
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/manifest.ttl
     INPUT
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/manifest.ttl.conf
     )
```

in between the two `configure_file`s, a person on Discord found [this](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2015-April/060350.html) which explains it